# why constructor of class has other class with new?

Tags: c++

i have the following code from a keccak tools. this project has several class. Keccak , KeccakF ,MultiRatePadding , ... are classes.please help me to understand "new" in in this code and why constructor of class has other class?

```
Keccak::Keccak(unsigned int aRate, unsigned int aCapacity)
:  (new KeccakF(aRate+aCapacity), new MultiRatePadding(), aRate) {}
```

Comment: Because pointers are needed? Why not look at the source and headers yourself, something which we can not do.

Comment: my guess would be because the super class constructor requires 3 arguments, KeccakF*, MultiRatePadding*, unsigned int)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the archaic pre-standard syntax where if you have only a single base class you can omit its name in the *mem-initializer*. That is, this constructor calls the base class constructor with the three arguments `new KeccakF(aRate+aCapacity)`, `new MultiRatePadding()`, `aRate`. Presumably the base class needs the `KeccakF` and `MultiRatePadding` objects and agrees to take ownership and free them in its destructor.

Comment: I've never heard of that syntax before (and I've been doing this a long time), but that is pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

This smells like Crypto++ but in any case...

`new` is a keyword in C++ used for object heap allocation. anything you allocate with `new` must have a corresponding `delete` invoked when it is no longer needed or it will be a memory leak.

Crypto++ in particular has a tendency to use pointer objects whilst also taking care of object deletion so you can simply just construct an anonymous heap object as a parameter as you see in your example.

In general however, just because something takes a pointer to a type does **not** mean you can just use `new` like this. If the callee doesn't `delete` then you've just created a mem leak.